# IOnic2 error in the services

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am importing a service inside another service but getting an error:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HttpserviceProvider
```

I have a auth service

```
@Injectable()
   export class AuthProvider {

constructor (public _httpService: HttpserviceProvider) {
  console.log ( 'Hello AuthProvider Provider' );
 }

tokenEvent: Subject<any> = new BehaviorSubject ( null );

login (user: any) {
   //logic to login, set token and emit an event of token set

}
}
```

Now in my HttpserviceProvider which is a custom http service which am using to attach access token I have

```
@Injectable ()
export class HttpserviceProvider {
  authtoken: string;

  constructor (private _http: Http ,
            private _storage: Storage ,
            private app: App ,
            private _authProvider: AuthProvider //this causes the error
  ) {

  this._authProvider.tokenEvent.subscribe ( res => {  
    if (res) {
      this._storage.get ( 'tokenuser' )
        .then ( token => {
          this.authtoken = token
        } );
    }
  })
}

post (url: string, body:any) { //sample http get request
   let headers = new Headers ();
   this.createGeneralHeaders ( headers );
   return this._http.get (
    ${this.getFullUrl ( url )}?access-token=${this.authtoken}` , headers, body );
  }
```

Why am I getting this error?

`Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HttpserviceProvider`

Comment: I'm not sure why do you inject `HttpserviceProvider` into `AuthProvider` and do it again opposite ?

Comment: you have a circular dependency